# Apply Hover event in Raphael paths

Tags: javascript, raphael

First problem: When I put a hover event on a raphael path, the effect is apply on every diffrent path. So, when I pass over the path, it changes the fill of that single path, after mouseout it should stay filled with an active color. If I put a hover event on another path "last hovered path" must be filled with default color.

Second problem: When i put hover event on text - back path not fills with color.
This is my code.

```
  var paths = {
  part_1: {
    name: 'part_1',
    path: 'M194 139c-21,35 -33,76 -33,119 0,6 0,12 1,18l-125 10c-1,-9 -1,-18 -1,-28 0,-51 11,-99 30,-142 41,10 84,17 129,23z',
    img: 'images/pol.png',
    desc: "Теплые\nполы"

  },
   part_2: {
    name: 'part_1',
    path: 'M209 400l-97 78c-41,-52 -69,-116 -75,-186l125 -11c5,44 22,85 48,118z',
    img: 'images/rad.png',
    desc: 'Котлы\nи радиаторы'
  },
   part_3: {
    name: 'part_1',
    path: 'M116 483l97 -79c5,5 9,11 14,16 25,25 57,45 92,56l-36 120c-55,-18 -104,-48 -144,-87 -8,-8 -16,-17 -23,-26l0 0z',
    img: 'images/lam.png',
    desc: 'Светодиодное\n освещение'
  },
   part_4: {
    name: 'part_1',
    path: 'M454 478l36 120c-32,10 -66,15 -101,15 -35,0 -68,-5 -101,-14l36 -120c20,6 42,9 64,9 22,0 44,-3 64,-9z',
    img: 'images/pol.png',
    desc: 'Натяжные\nпотолки,\nаксессуары '
  },
   part_5: {
    name: 'part_1',
    path: 'M565 405l97 79c-7,9 -15,17 -23,25 -40,39 -89,70 -144,87l-36 -120c35,-11 66,-31 92,-56 5,-5 10,-10 14,-16l0 0z',
    img: 'images/camera.png',
    desc: 'Системы\nбезопасности'
  },
   part_6: {
    name: 'part_1',
    path: 'M666 479l-97 -80c26,-33 42,-72 47,-116l125 10c-7,70 -34,134 -75,186z',
    img: 'images/vent.png',
    desc: 'Вентиля-\nционные\nсистемы'
  },
   part_7: {
    name: 'part_1',
    path: 'M742 286l-125 -10c0,-6 1,-12 1,-18 0,-44 -12,-84 -33,-119 45,-6 88,-13 129,-23 19,44 30,92 30,142 0,10 0,19 -1,28z',
    img: 'images/auto.png',
    desc: 'Гаражные\nворота,\nрольставни'
  }
}

function labelPath( pathObj, text, textattr )
{
    if ( textattr == undefined )
    textattr = { 'font-size': 18, fill: '#722d00', stroke: '#393738', cursor: 'pointer', 'stroke-width': 0, "text-anchor":"start", 'stroke-linejoin': 'round', 'font-family': 'Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif', 'font-weight': 'bold' };
    var bbox = pathObj.getBBox();
    var textObj = pathObj.paper.text( bbox.x + bbox.width / 4, bbox.y + bbox.height / 2, text ).attr( textattr );
    return textObj;
}

$(function(){

    var r = Raphael('map', 750, 625),
        attributes = {
            fill: '#FFC000',
            stroke: '#393738',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
            cursor: 'pointer'
        },
        attributes_circle = {
            fill: '#fff',
            stroke: '#393738',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round'
        },
        attributes_line = {
            fill: '#fff',
            stroke: '#fff',
            'stroke-width': 7,
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round'
        },
        attributes_min_circle = {
            fill: '#fff',
            stroke: '#fff',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round'
        },
        icon = {
            fill: '#FFC000',
            stroke: '#393738',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round'
        },
        icon_inner = {
            fill: '#fff',
            stroke: '#393738',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round'
        }
        arr = new Array();
        var id = 23;
        var a = 1;
    for (var country in paths) {

        var obj = r.path(paths[country].path);
        //Init text
        if(a <= 7){
            var path_a = r.path(paths['part_' + a].path);
            path_a.node.setAttribute("class","black_bor")
            var sst = String(paths['part_' + a].desc);
            labelPath( path_a, sst);
        }
        a++;

        //Fill stroke
        if(paths[country].name=='circle'){
            obj.attr(attributes_circle);
        }else if(paths[country].name=='line'){
            obj.attr(attributes_line);
        }else if(paths[country].name=='min_circle'){
            obj.attr(attributes_min_circle);
        }else if(paths[country].name=='icon_inner'){
            obj.attr(icon_inner);
        }else if(paths[country].name=='icon'){
            obj.attr(icon);
        }
        else{
            obj.attr(attributes);
        }
        arr[obj.id] = country;

        //Hover on element
        obj
        .hover(function(){
            if(paths[arr[this.id]].name=='part_1'){
            textattrs = { 'font-size': 18, fill: '#fff', stroke: '#393738', 'stroke-width': 0, "text-anchor":"start", 'stroke-linejoin': 'round', 'font-family': 'Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif', cursor: 'pointer', 'font-weight': 'bold' };
                var path_a = r.path(paths[arr[this.id]].path);
                path_a.node.setAttribute("class","black_bor")
                var sst = String(paths[arr[this.id]].desc);
                labelPath( path_a, sst, textattrs);
                this.animate({
                    fill: '#F3811E'
                }, 0);
                $(".img_behind").attr("src", paths[arr[this.id]].img);
            }
        }, function(){
            if(paths[arr[this.id]].name=='part_1'){
                var path_a = r.path(paths[arr[this.id]].path);
                path_a.node.setAttribute("class","black_bor")
                var sst = String(paths[arr[this.id]].desc);
                labelPath( path_a, sst);
                this.animate({
                    fill: attributes.fill
                }, 0);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Any ideas on how can I solve this problems?
Here is my work.
[Whole work on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6zkv77fa/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the first problem, you may need to reexplain it a bit, which part isn't working ?

For the 2nd part, you need to add pointer-events: none to stop it stealing the event..

```
text { pointer-events: none; }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zkv77fa/1/)

If I'm understanding the first bit correct, I think you will need to remove the hoverout, and just change the hover to remove any existing hover effects ?

Comment: @lan 2nd problem solved :) 1st problem: For example: I hovered first element, it's filled with balck color. When hoverout it should stay black colored. If I hover any other element the last hovered element must be filled with default color and this new hovered element must be filled with black color. Like an active menu with hover. Sorry, for my english!

Comment: I that case, I guess you need to rewrite as mentioned, don't use a hoverout. Store your hover elements in a set, and when you hover over a new element, reset the previously hoveredset and css, and hoveranimate the new one ?